# Is it possible to make a thread inside another thread in MFC?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have one problem about thread in MFC using `opencv`. Let I describe my problem first. I have one GUI that used to display video frame from camera. Hence, I must used one thread to get video from camera and display it in to `GUI`. It is done. However, I want to extend my problem such as: When video is displaying, I want to show that video in other window of opencv by command

```
IplImage* image2=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)original);
cvShowImage("Raw Image", image2);
cvReleaseImage(&image2);
```

As my knowledge, I need to create a new thread inside thread get video from camera. Is it possible to do it? Let see my code and could you give me some solution or suggestion to do that task? Thank you so much

This is my code

```
THREADSTRUCT *_param = new THREADSTRUCT;
_param->_this = this;
CWinThread* m_hThread;
m_hThread = AfxBeginThread (StartThread, _param);
```

In StartThread function, I will call the load video from camera such as

```
UINT Main_MFCDlg::StartThread (LPVOID param)
{
    THREADSTRUCT*    ts = (THREADSTRUCT*)param;
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    while (true)
    {
    Mat frame;
    Mat original;
    cap >> frame;
    if (!frame.empty()){
        original = frame.clone();           
        //Display video in GUI
        CDC* vDC_VIDEO;
        vDC_VIDEO=ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEO)->GetDC();
        CRect rect_VIDEO;
        ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEO)->GetClientRect(&rect_VIDEO);

        //Is it possible to create a thread in here to show video with other
        //delay time such as 1000ms
        //To call the function cv::imshow("Second window", original);

        }
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;// Delay 30ms for first window
    }
}
```

Notethat thread struct look like

```
//structure for passing to the controlling function
typedef struct THREADSTRUCT
{
    Main_MFCDlg*    _this;
} THREADSTRUCT;
```

Comment: Of course you can create a thread in a thread.  What do you think you are doing when you create your first thread?  Your program is running in its own thread and you spawn another thread to do other things.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Actually, I must control the video display with different frame per second.Because image processing takes some time, thus I need to display one window is raw frame (look like real time due to without image processing), and second window is image processing and it can has some delay. Hence, the first window is look like real image frame. And second window is image processing.

Comment: You have to be careful about accessing one window from not the thread that created it, that's a bit of a no-no.

Comment: I don't think that you need a thread (or, rather, another one) to get images from the camera. It might make sense to perform some operations in a background thread though. Anyhow, your assumption is probably wrong, which then begets the question what your actual problem is.

Comment: Personnaly I don't like your thread looping forever, it worries me about how to terminate gracefully, (ie from your main thread) Also I don't like MFC's autodeleting of threads but that's probably just me too...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt; At the first time, I tried to display video to MFC control without thread. It does not work. Hence, I write a thread that get video from camera and display in MFC control and it work well. Maybe I describe my step is not so clear. Now, I want to call the function cv::imshow of opencv without affect by delay of command waitKey(30). Can you help me

Comment: It does not work? Does it sit on the couch all day and watch movies? Seriously, that's completely useless as error description. I guess that the UI becomes unresponsive because it prevents pumping the message loop, but that doesn't mean that you always have to read from the camera in a separate thread.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. Let see my problem such as; I want to display video in separate window.

Comment: @AngusConnell there is no problem, in any cases, with threads looping forever, it's a normal practice.  Also, 'graceful termination' is a luxury that you will find that you can gladly do without, if at all possible, if you write complex. multithreaded apps.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can create a thread in a thread. You problem is: the worker thread should not access UI object directly in the UI thread, the details are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462347/mfc-accessing-gui-from-another-thread)

In your worker thread, after the background job is done, you can use [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) to send an message to the GUI and let it update.