# How to use a thread to process image with openCV and MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, opencv, mfc

I want to use a thread to display an image, but when I try, I  get the following: `error : a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object`.

The error occurs on the following line:

```
ShowImage(Image1, IDC_ShowImg);
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Here is my code:

**.h file**

```
class MFC_DMA : public CDialog
{
public:
    MFC_DMA(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~MFC_DMA();
    // Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFC_DMA };
private:
    CWinThread *worker_thread_;

protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX); // DDX/DDV support
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();

public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedCancel();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
    void ShowImage(IplImage * img, UINT ID);//imaging
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButtonstart();//Start thread
    afx_msg void OnStnClickedShowimg2();//Picture control
    afx_msg void OnStnClickedShowimg();//Picture control
    static UINT MyThreadButton2(LPVOID LParam);//thread
};
```

**.cpp file**

```
void MFC_DMA::ShowImage(IplImage* img, UINT ID)
{
    CDC* pDC = GetDlgItem(ID)->GetDC(); 
    HDC hDC = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
    CRect rect;
    GetDlgItem(ID)->GetClientRect(&rect);
    int rw = rect.right - rect.left;
    int rh = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    int iw = img->width;
    int ih = img->height;
    int tx = (int)(rw - iw) / 2;
    int ty = (int)(rh - ih) / 2;
    SetRect(rect, 0, 0, 512, 512);
    CvvImage cimg;
    cimg.CopyOf(img);
    cimg.DrawToHDC(hDC, &rect);
    ReleaseDC(pDC);
}

    //Structure Thread2
    struct MyThreadInfo2
    {
        HWND hWnd;
    }
    Info2;// Global Variables
    BOOL Start_Stop = NULL;
    //Thread code
    UINT MFC_DMA::MyThreadButton2(LPVOID LParam)
    {
        const int nSize2 = 32768;//I used PCI-e to receive data.
        const int width = 512;
        const int height = 512;
        const int channels = 1;
        const int step = 512 * 2; 
        CvSize img_size = cvSize(width, height);
        unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[nSize2];
        unsigned char *data2 = new unsigned char[nSize2];
        unsigned char *data_all = new unsigned char[nSize2 * 16];
        unsigned char *data_all2 = new unsigned char[nSize2 * 16];
        Image1 = cvCreateImageHeader(img_size, IPL_DEPTH_16U, channels);        
        Image2 = cvCreateImageHeader(img_size, IPL_DEPTH_16U, channels);
        cvCreateData(Image1);
        cvCreateData(Image2);
            
    while (Start_Stop)
        {
            MyThreadInfo2 *pInfo2 = (MyThreadInfo2*)LParam; 
            MFC_DMA *hWnd = (MFC_DMA*)CWnd::FromHandle(pInfo2->hWnd);
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < nSize2; j++)
                        {
                            data_all[nSize2*i + j] = 0;//Just want to test image
                                                       //0 is black
                            data_all2[nSize2*i + j] = 65535;//Just want to test                     image                                                       
                                                       //65535 is white
                        }
                }
                    cvSetData(Image1, data_all, step);
                    cvSetData(Image2, data_all2, step);
                    ShowImage(Image1, IDC_ShowImg);//have a error
                    ShowImage(Image2, IDC_ShowImg2); //have a error
            }
            Image1 = NULL;
            Image2 = NULL;
            delete[] data;
            delete[] data_all;
            delete[] data2;
            delete[] data_all2;
        }
        return(0);
    }
    void MFC_DMA::OnBnClickedButtonstart()//Open the thread
    {
            Info2.hWnd = this->m_hWnd;
            AfxBeginThread(MyThreadButton2, (LPVOID)&Info2);
            Start_Stop = TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to call the non-static function `MFC_DMA::ShowImage(...)` from the static function `MFC_DMA::MyThreadButton2(...)`. (you need to pass a _pointer to instance of `MFC_DMA`_ to the static thread function in order to be able to call `ShowImage`) It also seems that you're trying to access the GUI from a worker thread, which AFAIK is not a good idea (e.g. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462347/mfc-accessing-gui-from-another-thread) )

Comment: Thank you for your answer.but i don't know how to call the non-static function MFC_DMA::ShowImage from the static function MFC_DMA::MyThreadButton2(...).Could you give me a example?thanks

Comment: I noticed you already create the appropriate pointer from the window handle you passed to the thread function (somewhat roundabout, but not a big deal). So... `hWnd->ShowImage(Image1, IDC_ShowImg);`

Comment: Thank you Dan Mašek. You have solved my problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you already create the appropriate pointer from the window handle you passed to the thread function (somewhat roundabout, but not a big deal). So... `hWnd->ShowImage(Image1, IDC_ShowImg)`; 
Dan Mašek